# Asp.net MVC Areas URL seems case sensitive

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have created an area called /Live/Test in an MVC app and can get to this fine. However, if I visit /live/test I get a 404 error? I have tried adding the LowercaseUrls option but this just edits the hyperlinks that MVC generates.  Is there a way around this so all case combinations resolve to the route?

Thanks